# Eloquent where clause based on other tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

One of my Laravel models is called Property, which contains all the Real Estate properties within my application. Each Property contains a city and country.

Therefor I have the following relational tables:

```
City_property (holds city of properties)

| id | city_id | property_id |
|----|---------|-------------|
| x  | 2       | 1           |

City_country (holds country of city)

| id | country_id | city_id |
|----|------------|---------|
| x  | 3          | 2       |
```

So when fetching all my Properties, I want to where clause on the Country of the properties, so I'm able to only fetch Properties where country = 5 (for example).

Comment: Normally it would be easy with Laravel relations within the model files, but I'm using a small CMS that creates these database files.

Comment: which cms are you using, please?

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih TwillCMS

Comment: but you can still use relations? Nothing in that structure that is blocking.

Comment: @MartinHenriksen how?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [joins](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins) combined with a `where` method. For example:

```
Property::join('City_property', 'properties.id', '=', 'City_property.id')
  ->join('City_country', 'City_property.city_id' , '=', 'City_country.city_id')
  ->where('City_country.country_id', 5)
  ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query builders `whereHas` method, that performs queries on relations. I renamed your models into Property and Country for this example. This also presumes there is a country relation.

```
Property::whereHas('country', function ($query) {
    $query->where('id', 5);
})->get();
```